# PHP/SQL don't insert if two values exist

Tags: php, sql

I only want to insert if there are no entries where "name" and "email" exist together.

So it's ok if "name" exists with a different e-mail or vica versa.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email') ");
```

I want this done in one SQL statement for bette performance.

Comment: is this for mysql or mssql? the simple solution is to do a combined primary key to disallow the same combination of entries to be inserted. downside is you'll get php errors when executing that code unless it's put in a try catch, but sometimes even then. let me know if mssql or mysql and I'll show you a cool trick to do it in one shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both the columns (name,email) as composite primary key and use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to prevent php errors.

Comment: I have made both columns primary keys and used this query but it just inserts as normal mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='$name',email='$email'");

Answer (score 1):

make your primary key the pair (name,email).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make [name, email] as your primary key, set it up as a unique constraint.  That way no record with both values matching will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Have a primary key on name and email, then do this:

`REPLACE INTO list (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')`

replace is the same as insert, except if the values already exist it will overwrite them.

Comment: This will only work on MySQL, I think. And [beware of performance problems](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice).

Comment: I tried, this and got this error: #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: how large are your name and email fields?

Comment: I have shortened the email field which has stopped that error